# Handling intro and title screen

Tags: c#, game-design

What is the best way to handle the intro, title screen, and menus? I am contemplating that each of these could be a "scene" object of sorts. Perhaps in the game loop based on what needs to be done, a specific scene is loaded and everything that is contained within is executed. When that scene is no longer needed, it is unloaded.

Am I thinking about this correctly? I am not sure if "Scene" would be the best term to use in this case, but it is the best way I can describe it. Perhaps screen objects handled by a screen manager? If there is something more appropriate, I would love to know!

Also, for example I am thinking to have:

- Intro "scene"
- Main menu
- Settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to handle these, would be state enums. You would create enum, that has all the different states. Changing state, would cause program to run different code.

Define enum at somewhere:

```
public enum States
{
    Intro,
    MainMenu,
    Settings
}
```

Store your current state in a variable:

```
States gameState;
```

Set initial state at your game startup method.

```
void Init()
{
    gameState = States.Intro;
}
```

In your update method / mainloop, check the state and do something about it.

```
void Update()
{
    switch(gameState)
    {
        case States.Intro:
            ProcessIntroState();
            break;
        case States.MainMenu:
            ProcessMainMenuState();
            break;
        case States.Settings:
            ProcessSettingsState();
            break;
    }
}
```

This is very simple state handling setup. It is ok, for smaller games and projects, but for larger project, somekind of ScreenManager would be better.

Comment: Just keep in mind that using a simple `switch()` might be better here rather than using single `if`s without using `else`, although that could be obsolete based on how good the optimization is. Also defining `gameState` inside `Init()` won't make it global. (Editing that)

Comment: Yes, switch is better. Thanks for edit. Bit busy now irl.

Comment: dont use the word object or manager in class names...

Comment: By using word "ScreenManager" everyone here knows what i'm talking about. I do know about clean code, but that is what this class does.. manages screens. Changing it to handler or anything would not change the fact, that it manages screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GameScene approach too, where you have scenes that inherit from a base class, and a Stack to store them. I think is a good solution that lets you encapsulate different situations in the game in different modules.

```
 abstract class GameScene {
      public static readonly Stack<GameScene> Stack= new Stack<GameScene>();
      abstract void Update(GameTime time);
      virtual void Render() {}
 }

 class Intro : GameScene { 
     public override void Update()
     { 
         if (seconds>3)
         {
             GameScene.Pop();
             GameScene.Push(new Menu());
         }
     }
 }

 class Menu : GameScene { ... } 


 // In Game
 public void Update(gametime time) {
      GameScene.Stack.Peek().Update(time);          
 }
```

Above code is similar to the Game State Manager sample from microsoft: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management